# jQuery load() prevent link twice if parent page already have

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page use jquery load(page data will load into lightbox)

```
//index.php

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <a href='login.php'></a> //lightbox will load this page into index.php

//login.php
use jquery post data
```

Because layout problem on iphone, I decide to use `window.location` straight to the login.php page.

My problem is in login.php page don't have  jquery links

if I add this links in my login.php, when desktop device use lightbox load this page, it will load jquery twice

Is any way to prevent if parent page already have links don't links again, something like php require_once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very ez way to do this

In your window.location + '?mobile=1'

Than in your login.php

U can check if $_GET isset, if than echo the links

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamicaly include jQuery in `login.php` if `window.jQuery` not exists..

```
// Example:
if( typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined' ) {
    JavaScript.load("/jQuery.js");
}

// With callback (that’s the good thing):
if( typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined' ) {
    JavaScript.load("/jQuery.js", function() {
      // your code or whatever ...
    });
}


/** Testet with:
 *  - IE 5.5, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 (preview)
 *  - Firefox 3.6.3, 3.6.8
 *  - Safari 5.0
 *  - Chrome 5.0
 *  - Opera 10.10, 10.60
 */
var JavaScript = {
  load: function(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        loaded;
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    if (callback) {
      script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function() {
        if (!loaded) {
          callback();
        }
        loaded = true;
      };
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
};
```

- Example taken from this Gist https://gist.github.com/hagenburger/500716